# Why not extending to the whole disk implies have a zero

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, polynomials, differential-topology

> For any complex polynomial $p(z)$ of order $m$, we showed earlier that on a circle $S$ of sufficiently large radius $r$ in the plane,
>   $$\frac{p(z)}{|p(z)|}\quad \text{and}\quad \frac{z^m}{|z^m|}=\left(\frac{z}{r}\right)^m$$
>   are homotopic maps of $S \to S^1$. Thus $p/|p|$ must have the same degree as $(z/r)^m$ - namely, $m$. When $m>0$ we conclude $p/|p|$ will not extend to the whole disk of radius $r$, implying that $p$ must have a zero inside the disk.

So my questions are:

- What is $S$?
- Why not extending to the whole disk implies have a zero?

Comment: $S$ is "*a circle of sufficiently large radius $r$ in the plane*"

Comment: Oh, so $S$ has a sufficiently large radiu $r$, and $S^1$ is the unit circle... Thanks @ZevChonoles...

Comment: Thanks @zyx for the magic editing on what I mistakenly left..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As written, $S$ is "a circle of sufficiently large radius $r$".

If $p$ had *no* zero, then $z\mapsto \frac{p(z)}{|p(z)|}$ would define a map from the disk bounded by $S$ to the circle $S^1$

Comment: Ah, got it.... $p$ has no zero so that the map $p/|p|$ can be defined.. Thanks so much Hagen - I'll accept it as soon as acceptance become available. :-D